# Proof regarding infinite sets

Tags: analysis, elementary-set-theory

If $A$ is an infinite set and $B$ is a finite set prove that $A\setminus B$ is an infinite set.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $A=(A\setminus B)\cup(A\cap B)$

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $A-B = \{a-b | a \in A, b \in B \}$, if $B \neq \emptyset$, any fixing any $b$ produces a set of the same cardinality as $A$, so the conclusion follows.

Perhaps you meant $A - B = \{x |  x \in A, x \not \in B\}$?